# Need help adding a PPA

Tags: 12.04, ppa

This is the command i am typing in the terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gregory-halnaut/pcsx2.official.ppa
```

And this is the reply I am getting.

```
Cannot access PPA (https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~gregory-halnaut/+archive/pcsx2.official.ppa) to get PPA information, please check your internet connection.
```

The internet connection is fine.

Can anyone help me ?

I need BIOS ROMs for the pcsx2 emulator and in a tutorial on youtube I saw that I had to execute this command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install PS2 Emulator in Ubuntu, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pcsx2
```

(you just misspelled the name)

Answer (score 4):

You have mistyped one letter, an `l` instead of an `i` in `hainaut`.

The correct path is

https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~gregory-hainaut/+archive/pcsx2.official.ppa